# Sign in with Facebook if account already linked with google during initial signup in Firebase Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign in with facebook in the reinstallation of an android app. Initially I signed up using Google and successfully linked it with firebase.

But when I try to do with facebook it gives a

```
FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException
```

I read in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) that you can do so by

```
FirebaseUser prevUser = currentUser;
currentUser = auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await().getUser();
// Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data
// ...
```

but here `await()` method no longer exists. Also after searching a bit I found out this solution

```
Tasks.await(mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).getUser();
```

But this also gives an error when getting the current user which is already linked. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I'm not certain so I won't post this as an answer, but I do know that in the Firebase console, under Authentication>Sign-In Method, at the bottom where it says Advanced, there's a place to configure allowing multiple accounts to the same address. Since the documentation you've linked says you have to sign in using authentication flow first, you'd have to have the ability to create multiple accounts with the same email before you can merge them. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716?hl=en

Comment: Jen Person is right

Comment: how do I then merge the accounts @faruk

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in `.await()` method to get firebase user.
Use `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`instead.

So you implement firebase sign in with something like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "login success");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "login error");
                        }

                    }
                });
```

And implement `AuthStateListener` which is trigerred every time user state is changed:

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initAuthStateListener();

    }

private void initAuthStateListener() {

         authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    //user is not logged in
                } else {
                    //user is logged in 
                //logic to finish the activity and proceed to the app can be put here   
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
```

Note: `onAuthStateChanged` is trigerred once when `authStateListener` is added to firebase auth instance.

Also make sure `Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address` parameter is set on firebase console (Authentication >> SIGN-IN METHOD >> Advanced >> One account per email address (Change) ).

Comment: this won't help when user has already signed up once with google plus id..it gives FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException. Then we need to merge both accounts for which documentation says to use awaits(). but I am not able use that successfully

Comment: when you sign in with google and then sign in with facebook with the same email, firebase linkes those accounts to one by default (also check if the setting mentioned in the bottom of my answer is set in firebase console of your project)

Comment: the linking is not happening by default

Comment: linking of accounts with the same email is happening by default. There is an option in firebase console project 'Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address' which is on by default.

Comment: @dzikovskyy, I have "Prevent creation of multiple  accounts with the same email address" on by default and I am having the same problem as Shubham. It is saying that the email/account is already in use and that I should sign in using the right provider. Therefore, it is not linking it automatically. I could call `getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)` but the problem is that getCurrentUser() is null after I signed out (and the very reason why I am seeing the login activity again). Any solutions?